# How to convert image into less pixelate with ImageMagic

Tags: image, image-processing, imagemagick

I want to convert image in less pixelate with `ImageMagic` and I give a try with

convert -resize 20x20 -flop -gaussian-blur 1x5 -scale 100% -scale 500% -colorspace gray -quantize sRGB +dither /png.png /sam_pic.png

And its looking like the following image:

[image]

But I want to Increase pixel size that is `Image with less pixel`

Please suggest me how to do it and modify command.

Comment: I don´t understand what you want. Do you want a smooth image the same size as the original? What do you mean by "increase pixel size"? Do you want a larger image as a result? Please Explain exactly what you want.

Comment: @Mailerdaimon I want Image with less pixel with same size

Comment: Vijay, are you saying you want a pixelated version of the image? Perhaps if you post a *before* and *after* image so we can see what you want to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the solution.

Only change the size and increase the scale

```
convert -resize 18x18 -flop -gaussian-blur 1x5 -scale 110% -scale 500% -colorspace gray  /png.png /sam_pic.png
```

[image]